# Http: TLS handshake error from <IP:PORT> remote error: tls: bad certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, hashicorp-vault

We upgraded our AWS EKS cluster to version 1.25. After that, our Agent injectors refused to work properly showing the following messages:

```
2023-10-05T12:05:00.434Z [ERROR] handler: http: TLS handshake error from 10.31.164.232:36034: remote error: tls: bad certificate                                                                               │
│ 2023-10-05T12:05:00.434Z [ERROR] handler: http: TLS handshake error from 10.31.164.232:36018: remote error: tls: bad certificate
```

Here is our values.yaml file

```
injector:
  # Mount Path of the Vault Kubernetes Auth Method.
  authPath: "auth/qa-us"
server:
  ha:
    config: |
      listener "tcp" {
        tls_disable = 1
        address = "[::]:8200"
        cluster_address = "[::]:8201"
      }
      storage "dynamodb" {
        ha_enabled = "true"
        region     = "us-east-1"
        table      = "vault-dynamodb-table"
      }
      seal "awskms" {
        region     = "us-east-1"
        kms_key_id = "<KMS_ID>"
      }
```

Can anyone please let me know what I can do to fix it?

We made many attempts to fix it but it seems that nothing works.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you remove `tls_disable = 1` from your `values.yml` file, what do you get?